# Error trying to create new module and subscribe using ALAudioDevice service

Tags: python, audio, nao-robot, choregraphe

I have been trying to run a python script to get Nao's audio as a stream

Found the example directly on aldebaran's website

http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-8/dev/python/examples/audio/audio_soundprocessing.html#process-microphone-signals

I am trying to run it as is with only my robot's proper IP. Once it gets to the startProcessing function, it cannot find the new service created in ALAudioDevice and gives the following error

```
self.audio_service.setClientPreferences(self.module_name, 16000, 3, 0)
RUNTIMEERROR:   ALPROXY::ALPROXY
        CANT FIND SERVICE: SoundProcessingModule
[W] 1609782681.228570 42712 QITYPE.SIGNAL: DISCONNECT: NO SUBSCRIPTION FOUND FOR SIGNALLINK 14.
```

Any idea of what should change to be able to run that example?

Comment: Are you running NAOqi 2.8?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the link you provided, prior to setting the audio client preferences, you must register your service (or "module") to NAOqi:

```py
app.session.listen()
app.session.registerService("SoundProcessingModule", MySoundProcessingModule)
```

It is important that your service is registered prior to referring to it in other APIs such as `setClientPreferences`.

Comment: Hey Victor, I'm new to this, but is that not what is happening? Starting SoundProcessingModule and registering it in the next line (second to last), before doing the startProcessing?
Yet it still says it can't find the service. Should I register ir some other way?

`File "SoundProcessingModule.py", line 113, in <module>
    MySoundProcessingModule.startProcessing()
  File "SoundProcessingModule.py", line 42, in startProcessing
    self.audio_service.setClientPreferences(self.module_name, 16000, 3, 0)
RuntimeError:   ALProxy::ALProxy
        Can't find service: SoundProcessingModule`

Comment: The example has `app.session.registerService("SoundProcessingModule", MySoundProcessingModule)` right before `MySoundProcessingModule.startProcessing()`.
In theory this should work, so I must assume something is wrong in your code. Please share it and/or your full backtrace to investigate your issue deeper.

Comment: My current code is exactly the example code but with my robot's IP since I am running it from my computer and not from the robot itself. I just wanted first to test the example before doing any changes. I don't know why it is not working, let me know if I can post something that could give a better explanation of this.

Comment: Perhaps if you could share the logs of your program in a pastebin, and perhaps also of NAOqi, I could help further.

Comment: I have the same issue. Registering the service in the robot works (i ssh and run the python code there ), but not from a pc.

Comment: Also, if you list the service with `app.session.services()` the service is there on both the robot and the pc. Running from the robot, the service in the pc is also not found (same alproxy error). Sounds like a networking bug

Comment: Ok, I think I understand, sorry but I forgot a part of the solution. With the code I gave, you are registering a service via a client socket, so the address is only available to the service directory (which runs the paired server socket), and not to other clients such as `ALAUdioDevice`. To make it available, the session running from the PC should start a server socket by calling `session.listen(address)`. Make sure the address (usually ip:port) is reachable for the robot.

Comment: Do you have a complete working example you can show?

Comment: No, but I updated my answer accordingly. However I tested the original sample with NAOqi 2.1 and it worked, but it is plausible that NAOqi 2.8 works differently.

Comment: Please share your NAOqi logs if possible, there is something fishy in the fact that in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69505667/how-do-you-use-a-different-speech-recognition-engine-with-nao you say you managed to use `ALMemory` events, which rely on the same mechanism.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I run into the same issue when trying to do this inside a Docker container. The same code runs fine from the host PC though.

Comment: @user1587520 you have a different issue. You need your docker to open a port to so that the address you provide in the `session.listen(address)` is actually reachable from the robot. @user27221 is it possible that this is your issue? Did you check that you have no firewall blocking the port, or that you are not working in a VM?

Comment: @VictorPaléologue Thanks for your answer, I tried to set `session.listen('0.0.0.0:9558')` and open that port on the container. The logs showed that it is used  by the Session. I checked with telnet from the host machine that I connect to the port. I also tried to register a dummy service to the session in the container and tested that I can get and run it from a qi.Application that I started in the Python REPL on the Robot. That worked fine, even without opening the port on the container.  Somehow it looks like there is still a different (dynamic) port used. Running directly on the host works.

Comment: @VictorPaléologue Code is here: https://github.com/leolani/cltl-backend-naoqi/blob/test/src/test_so.py

Comment: This test shows you are registered, but not that the `test` method can be called properly from the robot. You'll need another script on the robot to call that method to properly test the service registration.

Comment: @VictorPaléologue Sorry, forgot to include the code on the robot. If we run

`app = qi.Application(["Test App Robot", "--qi-url=localhost:9559"])
app.start()
test_service = app.session.service("TestModule")
test_service.test()`

there it works, we see the invocation in the container and the result on the robot. I added to code to the link above as well. Nevertheless, if I register the SoundProcessingModule the same way in the container, the ALAudioDevice doesn't seem to see it.